# Missing required parameter for Route in Laravel tests

Tags: laravel

I want to test one of the methods that changes the product. The method works on this route

```
Route::patch('/{id}/edit-product/{product}/edit', [ProductController::class, 'editProduct'])->name('editProduct');
```

In my test, I call patch and pass this route there and get an error

```
$response = $this->actingAs($user)->patch(route('editProduct', ['id' => $user->id, 'product' => 1]), [
    'title' => 'Updated product',
    'description' => 'Updated Product description',
    'price' => 100,
    'main_photo' => UploadedFile::fake()->image('avatar.jpg', 500, 500)->size(100),
    'visible' => true,
    'additional_photos' => $new_img,
]);
```

And every time I get the following error

`Missing required parameter for [Route: showProduct] [URI: {id}/edit-product/{product}/show] [Missing parameter: product].`

I do not quite understand what is the reason for this error, since the method itself works properly, but the test does not want to work. It seems that I am passing an additional parameter, but the test still swears that it does not exist. What could be the problem?

Comment: The route you are testing and the error you are getting for the route is different.
- You are testing for `{id}/edit-product/{product}/edit` and you are getting error for `{id}/edit-product/{product}/show`

Check if you are calling `route('showProduct')` somewhere in `ProductController@editProduct`

Comment: One thing is what you pass as second parameter on route() and another is what you pass as second parameter on patch(). On route you need to pass an array for {id} and {product} and the payload for your product update goes on the patch() (i don' t remember now if it' s second or third param since you can pass an array of headers as well)